# Accidentally killed /bin/bash process.. what should i do?

Tags: bash, unix, amazon-ec2

as the topic suggest, i accidentally killed the wrong process. nothing is working for me now. what should i do?

I have tried to install, reinstall but it does not work.

```
whatever cmd i type just returns nothing
ls
cmd
pwd
```

Comment: Can you just restart your machine?

Comment: "Hello, this is IT, have you tried turning it off and on again"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you had ssh'ed to the machine and killed your own shell, I would suggest that you just try to `ssh` to the machine again and start over.

If that doesn't work, reboot the server via the AWS console.

Comment: i tried booting, its the same guys

Comment: Then you should spin up a new instance from your AMI. EC2 instances are supposed to be throw-away resources, right?